# Function params not recognised within a-list?

Tags: function, common-lisp

I am using dexator to do a post request. I am updating a contact database.

Here is my code:

```
(defun upload-post (firstname email &optional first-line)
  
  (dex:post NEW-LEAD-URL
        :headers '((:content-type . "application/json"))
        :content '(("email" . 'email)
               ("first_name" . firstname)
               ("custom_attributes" . '(("first_line" . first-line))))))
```

I get the error that `firstname, email and first-line` are defined but not used.

Notice that I tested quoting the `email`. That didn't work.

Why are the params being ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because symbols inside a [quoted](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm) list (`email`, `firstname`, `first-line`) won't evaluate.

Quote (`'`) stops all evaluation, so values of variables `firstname`, `email` and `first-line` aren't used and you will send a request, where `"email"` has value `email`, `"first_name"` has value `firstname` and so on.

You could create that request list with [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_list_.htm) and [`cons`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/f_cons.htm), so all symbols are properly evaluated, or use [backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) and comma:

```
(defun upload-post (firstname email &optional first-line)
  (dex:post NEW-LEAD-URL
            :headers '((:content-type . "application/json"))
            :content `(("email" . ,email)
                       ("first_name" . ,firstname)
                       ("custom_attributes" . (("first_line" . ,first-line))))))
```

Just note that your naming is inconsistent- `firstname` vs `first-line`.

Comment: Beautiful. This is very useful Martin! As for the inconsistencies, I don't understand. Firstname and first-line are different crm fields.